# I want to make Excel read a value in Calc and copy it to my sheet in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, reference

I have over 500 files of Calc (.ods) and each one of them has some values that I want to reference/copy to a Excel's file. 
Those Calc's files are always updated and I want my Excel file to be update as soon as I open it. 
How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to S.O! Have you tried anything? If so, please, provide the code, take a look to the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Friendly reminder: StackOverflow is not a "we code for you" service provider.[Introduction to VBA](https://blog.udemy.com/excel-macros-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

## Background

You can achieve this by adding a macro in Excel that has the Workbook_Open Subroutine. This will allow you to run a series of operations when the workbook first opens.

Excel supports ODS file format so it can be opened like any other spreadsheet. Since you will need to extract values from multiple Calc files, you can use a loop control structure to process each Calc file and place the data into the macro-enabled Excel worksheet cells.

## Example

In this example, the main spreadsheet has a worksheet named "Config Data" which stores some configuration data that VBA uses to complete the operation. This data includes the directory and the extension of the files for manageability purposes. if you would like the example files, I can upload them and provide them to you. However, I'm unsure if we are allowed to provide links to file downloads here.

### Setup

There are 4 sample .ods files placed in the C:\test directory. The files are mostly identical. These are the files that will be pulled by the macro and processed. In the Excel spreadsheet that will contain the macro, there is a button added that allows on-demand update (execution of the macro).

### Code

Below is sample code that will allow you to process each file. Please read the comments in the code for details.

```
'Allows you to execute code when the workbook first opens.
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    GetFiles
End Sub

'Subroutine that actually processes the files. This subroutine makes a list of each spreadsheet's filename along with all of its worksheets. A conditional statement is also included to display how copying and pasting of cell range can be achieved.
Public Sub GetFiles()

    'Create all variables used in this subroutine
    Dim directory As String, fileName As String, currentWorkbook As Workbook, sheet As Worksheet, i As Integer, j As Integer

    'Stop screen updating, events, and alerts until this subroutine has finished execution.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Pull the directory and file extension data from the "Config Data" worksheet.
    directory = Sheets("Config Data").Cells(1, 2)
    fileExt = Sheets("Config Data").Cells(2, 2)

    'Find the first file in the specified directory with the specified file extension.
    ' If the Dir function finds multiple files matching the file extention, the function can be called again without any arguments to return the next file.
    fileName = Dir(directory & "*." & fileExt)

    ' Start a loop control structure to process each file.
    Do While fileName <> ""
        i = i + 1
        j = 2

        ' Store filename of each spreadsheet in its own row
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) = fileName
        Set currentWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=directory & fileName)

        If fileName = "StockChart.ods" Then
            'Copying a range from the current workbook that is being processed
            currentWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:G21").Copy
            'Pasting a range to the current workbook that is running the macro
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F11").PasteSpecial
        End If

        ' For each worksheet in the current workbook, the worksheet name is being stored in the column next to its workbook filename.
        For Each sheet In currentWorkbook.Worksheets
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j) = sheet.Name
            j = j + 1
        Next sheet

        ' Close current workbook
        currentWorkbook.Close

        ' Check if more files exist that match the file extension provided.
        fileName = Dir()
    Loop

    'Enable screen updating, events, and alerts
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```